# apt-get install python-minimal:armhf removed KDE; what now?

Tags: debian, apt, kde

Environment: Debian 8.0 (Jessie), x64, KDE desktop, with armhf architecture added for cross-compilation to BeagleBone.

While building Boost 1.55, I needed the python package. Makes sense, as Boost has some Python integration stuff. `apt-get install python:armhf` failed, on "held packagages" but that apparently is a known bug (I have no held packages). `apt-get install python-minimal:armhf` was accepted but suggested removing a number of packages including a lot of Boost 1.55. That wasn't entirely weird because I had a native version (isntead of the correct `:armhf`). However, that also removed the whole GUI dropping me at a text prompt (!).

Obviously an `apt` bug, there is no way in the world why a python package for ARM should affect KDE for x64. But how do I get my GUI back?

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo aptitude install kde-desktop`

Comment: `kde-desktop` was the package I needed.